# Detect when html input required true is working

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form

```
<form id="newRecord">
  <input type="text" required/>
</form>

<button form="newRecord" type="submit">Submit</button>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EZwRjK

When the field is empty, and you click the button, you get a "Please fill out this field." pop up next to the field. Is there a way to detect if that pop up appears with JavaScript?

Comment: Not as far as I know, however with JavaScript you could detect if the attribute was present and then check the actual content of the input yourself.

Comment: You can use the validation API, with some event listeners for, say, keyup, but that's probably the closest you can get: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Data_form_validation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In HTML5, the pseudo-class `:invalid` is applied to any input that triggers the "This field is required" dialog box.

If you put the listener on your button, you could find out if the dialog box appeared or not by checking to see if there were any inputs marked `:invalid`...

```
$("#newRecord input[type=submit]").click(function() {
    if ($("#newRecord input:invalid").length) {
        //The popup appeared
    } else {
        //The popup did not appear
    }
});
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/vruxxcsx/5/)

Answer (score 3):

In fact you can. You can use `checkValidity()` method. It returns true if the element contains a valid data.

```
$(function() {
  $("#submit-button").click(function () {
     // using jquery
     console.log($("#input-text")[0].checkValidity());

     // using javascript
     var input = document.getElementById("input-text");
     console.log(input.checkValidity());
  });
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1xwp7xu4/)

**Update**

Seems the pop up is not showing when using `type="button"`.
A work around I found is to use `$("input").on("blur", function () {` instead.

So it should be now:

```
$(function() {
  $("input").on("blur", function () {
     console.log($("#input-text")[0].checkValidity());
     var input = document.getElementById("input-text");
     console.log(input.checkValidity());

     // checking as a whole
     console.log("Form - ", $("#newRecord")[0].checkValidity());
  });
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1xwp7xu4/3/)

Comment: If you can only call `checkValidity();` on a single element, wouldn't you have to loop through all inputs and call the function for each one?

Comment: Just found out that you can also use that on the form so you don't have to loop and go through all the inputs. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1xwp7xu4/2/)

Comment: @TylerZika Ah good spot. I've updated my answer, check it out.

Comment: @RobinCarloCatacutan on your updated fiddle, the button is still of type submit. Is there a way to make the pop up still appear as type button?

Comment: @TylerZika Yes, meant it like that, so it shows the pop up with the error message in it.

Answer (score 0):

**REACT / NEXT.JS**

In my case, it was because the 'input' tags were required and were **not in the viewport** (not visible) when submitting on my form.
The form was hidden when a useState was false `const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false)`, then it was necessary to change the state to true so that the form would appear and the "fill these fields" message.

Solution was with **`onInvalid()`** property

```
<input onInvalid={() => setIsOpen(true)} type='radio' required />
```